Does the C++ standard library have function types that are non-copy-constructible?
I want to pass a bunch of lambdas around without having to make copies.
This is the declaration of one of the lambdas
[
    promise = std::move(promise),
    namedSeries = std::move(namedSeries)
] mutable

Since promise and namedSeries are being converted to rValues, the lambda is not copy constructible, so it can not be passed to a function with parameter type std::function.
For a work-around, I can wrap the lambda parameters in pointers, but that is extra boilerplate.
Is there a better solution? Perhaps a function type that does not require the lambda to be copy-constructible?

For the most part the standard expects that it can copy any function object passed to it.  There might be some that do otherwise but the majority do a copy

There are std::function_ref (or std::move_only_function) that can be used instead of std::function to accept non-copyable types. But those are fairly new, C++26 and C++23 respectively.

FYI, your lambda is not copyable not because of std::move, but because the type of promise and/or of namedSeries are not copyable.

Looks like std::move_only_function works! All the posts I checked did not mention it. Probably because it is newer.

I don't understand.  Rather than using lambdas, why not create functions?  Functions (pointer to) and function objects can be passed around and IMHO, have less issues than lambdas.

"promise and namedSeries are rValues" - what?  That doesn't make much sense.  There are quite obviously things in your code called promise and namedSeries that qualify as lvalues...  and I'm completely confused why you think them being rValues means the lambda isn't copy constructible.  The lambda might not be copyable, but your reasoning why reads like random words piled in a salad?

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont Does std::move not convert them to rValues?

@JohnGlen rvalue/lvalue are expression and reference categories.  std::move casts some expression to being an rvalue reference expression.  promise = std::move(promise) thus takes the expression promise, casts it to an rvalue reference expression, then creates a lambda-local variable promise and constructs it from that rvalue reference expression, effectively moving the outer scope promise into a lambda-scope promise object.  Within the lambda, promise has a name, so the expression promise is an lvalue.  Anything with a name in an expression is an lvalue.

@JohnGlen int&& x = 7; - x is an rvalue reference, but in x+1 the expression x is an lvalue expression; naming any variable produces an lvalue (lvalue is short for left hand of = value).  std::move(x) casts the lvalue expression x into being an rvalue expression.  std::forward<int>(x) does the same, as does std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) - std::forward is a conditional move.  I know, this is complicated.  I am probably using subtly wrong words that don't match the standard, which makes it worse.
